# Remove object from array by sub array key value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects:

And I want to remove the object, that has a specific date (**2020-09-24** in this example) in the excluded_dates Array to output the new Array like this:

```
  outcome = [
    {
      title: '"test1"',
      excluded_dates: false,
    },
    {
      title: '"test2"',
      excluded_dates: [
        { excluded_date: "2020-09-12" },
        {
          excluded_date: "2020-09-17",
        },
      ],
    }
   ];
```

For this, I was thinking of using double filtering. I also tried some(), but that is for Arrays, not an Array of Objects.

```js
const data = [
        {
          title: '"test1"',
          excluded_dates: false,
        },
        {
          title: '"test2"',
          excluded_dates: [
            { excluded_date: "2020-09-12" },
            {
              excluded_date: "2020-09-17",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          title: '"test3"',
          excluded_dates: [
            {
              excluded_date: "2020-09-16",
            },
            {
              excluded_date: "2020-09-24",
            },
          ],
        },
      ];



const outcome = data.filter(function (event) {
    if (event.excluded_dates) {
      return event.excluded_dates.filter(
        (date) => date.excluded_date === "2020-09-24"
      );
    }
  });

 console.log(outcome);
```

This ofcourse doesn't work as expected. What am I'm missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to return `true` if the object does not have an `excluded_dates` property. Also, since you are only looking for one date, you can replace your second use of [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
const outcome = data.filter((event) => {
  return !(
    event.excluded_dates && // if there is no `excluded_dates` property, return `true`
    event.excluded_dates.some( // otherwise, try to find the date. if found, return `false`
      ({ excluded_date }) => excluded_date === "2020-09-24"
    )
  );
});
```

---

Code snippet example:

```js
const data = [{
    title: '"test1"',
    excluded_dates: false,
  },
  {
    title: '"test2"',
    excluded_dates: [{
        excluded_date: "2020-09-12"
      },
      {
        excluded_date: "2020-09-17",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: '"test3"',
    excluded_dates: [{
        excluded_date: "2020-09-16",
      },
      {
        excluded_date: "2020-09-24",
      },
    ],
  },
];

const outcome = data.filter((event) => {
  return !(
    event.excluded_dates &&
    event.excluded_dates.some(
      ({ excluded_date }) => excluded_date === "2020-09-24"
    )
  );
});

console.log(outcome);
```

Comment: This works, but can you explain what does this code does? You have a shorthand to check if excluded_dates exist, but why are you returning true for the else?

Comment: [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) runs a given function through every element of an array. If the function returns `true`, it will keep the element in the array. Otherwise, it will remove it from the array.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `filter`:

```js
let data = [
  { index: 0, exclude: ['Monday'] },
  { index: 1, exclude: ['Tuesday', 'Thursday'] },
  { index: 2, exclude: ['Wednesday'] },
];

data = data.filter(el => !el.exclude.includes('Tuesday'));

console.log(data);
// data = { index: 0, exclude: ['Monday'] }, { data: 2, exclude: ['Wednesday'] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Return `true` if event has not the `excluded_dates` property, because those you'll want to keep in every scenario.

Instead of a nested filter check if every `excluded_date` in the `excluded_dates` array is not equal to `"2020-09-24"` with the [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method, which returns true or false based if *every* callback evaluated true or not.

```js
const data = [{
    title: '"test1"',
    excluded_dates: false,
  },
  {
    title: '"test2"',
    excluded_dates: [{
        excluded_date: "2020-09-12"
      },
      {
        excluded_date: "2020-09-17",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: '"test3"',
    excluded_dates: [{
        excluded_date: "2020-09-16",
      },
      {
        excluded_date: "2020-09-24",
      },
    ],
  },
];

const outcome = data.filter(function(event) {
  if (event.excluded_dates) {
    return event.excluded_dates.every(
      (date) => date.excluded_date !== "2020-09-24"
    );
  }
  return true;
});

console.log(outcome);
```

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track. You can even use some() for the excluded_dates array. Here is a working function

```js
data.filter((d) => {
 if (Array.isArray(d.excluded_dates)) {
  return d.excluded_dates.some((date) => date.excluded_date === '2020-09-24');
 }

 return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you were at right track, only need to change the condition.
Filter always return item where condition is matching.
you need to check if excluded_date is false or excluded_date array doesn't contain the date. So in inner filter If we get length 0,it means date is not present in the array and so include in expected output.

```js
const data = [{
    title: '"test1"',
    excluded_dates: false,
  },
  {
    title: '"test2"',
    excluded_dates: [{
        excluded_date: "2020-09-12"
      },
      {
        excluded_date: "2020-09-17",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: '"test3"',
    excluded_dates: [{
        excluded_date: "2020-09-16",
      },
      {
        excluded_date: "2020-09-24",
      },
    ],
  },
];

const outcome = data.filter(event => (!event.excluded_dates || event.excluded_dates.filter(
    (date) => date.excluded_date === "2020-09-24"
  ).length == 0))

console.log(outcome);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried using Foreach and filter operators

```js
const data = [
    {
      title: '"test2"',
      excluded_dates: [
        { excluded_date: "2020-09-12" },
        {
          excluded_date: "2020-09-17",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      title: '"test3"',
      excluded_dates: [
        {
          excluded_date: "2020-09-16",
        },
        {
          excluded_date: "2020-09-24",
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
  
  
  
  data.forEach(function(item, idx) {
      item.excluded_dates.filter(function(item1) {
          if( item1.excluded_date === "2020-09-24" ) {
              
              return data.pop(idx);
          }
      });
  });
  
  console.log(data);
```